# jQuery to pause and play audio and change icons

Tags: jquery, css, html, font-awesome

I am trying to play an MP3 file on my webpage, but would like to use an option for the user to choose whether to play the music or not. So I need a button to toggle between play and stop.

HTML

```
<li><a href="#" id="music"><i class="fa fa-music fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#music").click(function() {
  //$("blockquote").removeClass("animated rollIn").addClass("animated hinge");
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/om_cut.mp3');

    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

   audioElement.play();
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-music fa-stop');
});
```

So I am able to play the music successfully on click and when I tap on the play icon, my icon also changes to the stop icon.

But I want that when I click on the stop icon, the music stops and the icon changes back to the play icon. I am not able to understand how to add the second click event to this icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var playing = false;
var initDone = false;

var audioElement = null;

$("#music").click(function() {
  if (playing) {
    // Stop playing
    audioElement.pause();
  } else {
    // Start playing
    if (!initDone) {
      initDone = true;

      audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/om_cut.mp3');

      audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
      }, false);
    }

    audioElement.play();
  }

  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-music fa-stop');
  playing = !playing;
});
```

Comment: Nice, you actually prevented creating the element again every time play is pressed. Good job. +1 for using the tools provided.

Comment: @Duncan: Awesome Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might it will work for you :)

HTML :

```
<a href="#" id="music" class="play"><i class="fa fa-music fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

JS :

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/om_cut.mp3');
$(document).on('click', '.play', function() {
        audioElement.play();
    $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
});

$(document).on('click', '.pause', function() {
        audioElement.pause();
    $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
});
```